# Do repositories require an interface?

Tags: php, laravel

I have been reading greatly into using the repository pattern with laravel and I have seen the DI done with both the repository itself and also with its interface.

My question is, does a repository require an interface to be effective?

```
class Repository {
     public function foo () {
          return "Hi";
     }
}
class RepositoryController {
    private $test;
    public function __contruct(Repository $test) {
        $this->test = $test;
    }

    public function do() {
        echo $test->foo();
    }

}
```

vs:

```
interface RepositoryInterface {
    function foo (string $text)
}
class Repository implements RepositoryInterface {
     public function foo ($text) {
          return $text;
     }
}
class RepositoryController {
    private $test;
    public function __contruct(RepositoryInterface $test) {
        $this->test = $test;
    }

    public function do() {
        echo $test->foo();
    }

}
```

Comment: "to be effective" --- what does this exactly mean?

Comment: @zerkms I thought the whole point of the repository pattern is to manipulate the data through an abstraction without touching the model. Using the interface allows this. But I was wondering a reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No. You don't have to use an interface. The interface just ensures you use the same methods correctly in each class which implements the interface.

For example, if you use a findOne(id) method. You know it will always receive an id and you can specify its type and what it has to return.

In large applications, it can be very useful and maintain order.

If you are unsure, from my experience it's better to try a few different ways to see which one fit your needs. Unless you don't have the time, then should simply use whatever is more common.

I used the interface and I think it worked well once a new developer came in and better understood what is allowed all repositories.